# Converting a correlateion coefficient function from NumPy to Dask

Tags: python, numpy, distributed, dask

I'm trying to evaluate dask by converting a method from [thunder](http://thunder-project.org/) (using Spark), to the equivalent numpy version, but I'm not sure how to write this using dask/distributed.

In thunder, I can take a stack of images, convert it to a series, and correlate against some signal:

```
imgs = thunder.images.fromrandom((10, 900, 900))
series = imgs.toseries()
signal = series[5, 5, :]
correlated = series.correlate(signal)
```

The numpy version looks like this:

```
series = numpy.random.rand(900, 900, 10)
signal = series[5, 5, :]

reshaped = series.reshape(900 * 900, 10)

correlated = numpy.asarray(
    map(lambda x: numpy.corrcoef(x, signal)[0, 1], reshaped))
)
final = correlated.reshape(900, 900)
```

I'm looking for some tips on how to convert this into something for distributed in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

imgs = da.random.random((10, 900, 900), chunks=(1, 900, 900))
reshaped = imgs.reshape((10, 900 * 900))
```

If you wanted to correlate your images against each other

```
result = da.corrcoef(reshaped)
result.compute()
```

Or against some other signal

```
signal = np.random.random(900 * 900)
result = reshaped.map_blocks(np.corrcoef, signal, dtype=signal.dtype)
result.compute()
```

However, I'm not very familiar with your application, so the response above may be flawed.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it's easier to see this now!

However, I get a `MemoryError` when I call `result.compute()`, running in threaded mode. I'll try to reproduce this on a different box just to make sure.

Comment: I would not be surprised by a memory error in the `da.corrcoef` case (it's hard to do this operation in a low-memory way).  I would not expect a memory error in the second case.  If you want to spill to disk you can try the distributed scheduler: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html

Comment: I think I'm getting an out of memory error because the only way I could figure out how to chunk it was by 900. Your example flipped the dimensions...I need to start with a set of say 10 images that are 900x900 and then flip into a time series of size (900, 900, 10). To do that, I started `imgs` with `chunks=900`, so my `reshaped` ended up having a `chunksize=(810000, 10)`. I would need to only correlate against the signal, the last block you have above, but I can't figure out the correct chunk size.